# Is it a good idea to integrate product management and development tasks in one Jira project?

Tags: software-development, jira

I am considering streamlining all product-related pipelines, from discovery to delivery, into one Jira Project. My idea is to use boards to have issues and tasks flowing forward and being separated and following the workflow of each teams. Is that a good idea, or am I trying to fit two processes that are too far apart into the same framework?

Comment: Considering each company could have very special flows "from discovery to delivery", it's hard to give a canonical answer. OTOH, anything that could be done that'd increase transparency (and collaboration as a byproduct) should be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Who's going to look at your boards, and why?
You should use Jira to meet your business needs and processes, not the other way around. So ask yourself and others:

1. Do we need to track both?
2. Is there anyone who cares about dev tasks but not management tasks?
3. Is there anyone who cares about management tasks but not dev tasks?
4. Is there anyone who cares about both?

And then proceed accordingly.

For what it's worth, what I did was I made my workflow scheme contain two workflows, one for stories/tasks/bugs and one for epics, with mutually exclusive statuses. Then I set up two separate boards, one for each.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how are tasks managed? What are the required permissions? Intuitively, for most small and medium-sized projects, I would probably keep them in one, but without details, it is hard to give a definite opinion. Another option is to keep separate Jira projects for each team and group them into a portfolio with a Jira addon like BigPicture what will allow you to manage the pipelines and track progress both on individual sprint and grouped projects level.